# Why can an element of a Hilbert space be written as this sum?

Tags: proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning

From Understanding Machine Learning:

> Let $w^*$ be an optimal solution of this equation:
>
> $$\min_w (f(\langle w, \psi(x_1)\rangle, \dots , \langle w, \psi(x_m)
> \rangle) + R(||w||))$$
>
> where $\psi:X \rightarrow \text{Hilbert Space (H)}, x_i \in X,$ and $
>  R : \Bbb R_{+} \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a monotonically nondecreasing
>   function.
>
> **Then $w^*$ can be written as $w^* = \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i\psi(x_i)+u$
>   where $\langle u,\psi(x_i) = 0 \rangle$ for all $i$**.

Why can $w^*$ be written in this way?

Comment: Let $V$ the space spanned by the $\psi(x_i)$. What you are trying to prove is that $w^*$ is the sum of an element orthogonal to $V$ and an element of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write $w=w_a+w_b$ where $w_a$ is in the span of $\lbrace \psi(x_i)\rbrace_{i\in[m]}$ and $w_b$ is orthogonal to this space.

Then you get that $\langle w,\psi(x_i)\rangle = \langle w_a,\psi(x_i)\rangle$ and $\lVert w \rVert=\sqrt{\lVert w_a\rVert^2 + \lVert w_b\rVert^2}\geq \lVert w_a\rVert$ with equality if and only if $w_b=0$. Hence, since $R$ is monotically nondecreasing, the minimum can only be achieved if $w_b=0$ which proves your statement.